# Changing txt layer Data Source in QGIS only using Python console?

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-3, data-source

I want to change the data source of a layer (non geometric, just a table of fields) created from a .txt file. I know how to do it manually but I want to do it with the Python console. I have tried the setDataSource() command but I don't quite understand the arguments.

```
from qgis.core import QgsDataSourceUri

uri = QgsDataSourceUri()
uri.setDataSource("Path_to_new_source_txtfile","layer_name","memory")
```

This is the code I tried to use to change the source file, it didn't get me any error but it didn't change the source file either.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to call the `setDataSource()` function from the *actual layer*, not from the class itself:

```
layer = iface.activeLayer()
layer.setDataSource("Path_to_new_source_txtfile","layer_name","memory")
```